# Create Word document from Excel data

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am creating a Word document which I will print onto a sheet of stickers. 
I want the document to have around 333 pages, with each page having 30 stickers with unique codes (which can be redeemed through a website). I have 10,000 codes in total.

I have an Excel spreadsheet with the 10,000 codes in individual rows.
 I want to grab each code from the cell in Excel and then place it into the corresponding text box.
What is the best way to do this? Would I use vba code or something else?

Here is an image:

[image: sample image]

Comment: Looks like a [*MAIL MERGE*](http://www.wikihow.com/Perform-a-Mail-Merge-in-Word-2010) but haven't tried it on a Textbox. So you might want to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mail merge in Word with the Excel doc as the data source.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a job for mail merge. Use Word, layout a table with the stickers, connect to the Excel file, put the merge fields into the table and run the merge.

Word has the Mail Merge Wizard to guide you through the steps (Mailings Ribbon > Start Mail Merge > Step-by-Step Mail Merge wizard). It also has many, many, many brands and sizes of labels pre-formatted and ready to go. If you need more instructions, there are about a gazillion free tutorials about mail merge on the internet.

You will need to add a header row with a label for the column to your Excel file. Word needs that to identify the field of the data source.